# Pagination on array stored in a document field

Tags: mongodb, pagination

Let's say I've got a collection People in mongo database:

```
[{
    id: 1,
    name: "Tom",
    animals: ["cat", "dog", "fish", "bear"]
},
{
    id: 2,
    name: "Rob",
    animals: ["shark", "snake", "fish", "bear", "panda"]
},
{
    id: 3,
    name: "Matt",
    animals: ["cat", "fish", "bear"]
}]
```

For the purpose of REST API I need to create a pagination system for viewing people's animals and return only 3 per request. So for example if you go to `/people/2`the API should return this array:

```
["shark", "snake", "fish"]
```

I'm trying to get this result using Mongo methods. Here's my attempt:

```
db.getCollection('people').find({id: 2}, {animals: 1, _id:0}, {limit: 3})
```

Unfortunatelly it doesn't work like that and returns the whole object. Can anybody tell me how to do it?

Answer (score 18, accepted):

For you problem you need the [**`$slice`**](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/projection/slice/#proj._S_slice) projection operator instead of `limit`. The later limits the number of **documents** returned as a result of the query. Instead, the `$slice` operator is intended for exactly what you need.

Here is an example how to use it in your use case:

```
> db.getCollection('people').find({id: 2}, {_id: 0, animals: {$slice: [0, 3]}})
{
    "id" : 2,
    "name" : "Rob",
    "animals" : [
        "shark",
        "snake",
        "fish"
    ]
}
```

Comment: This works great. Thank you! Is there similar method for sorting items in array?

Comment: There is a way to store the array sorted using `$each` and `$sort` operators. But if you want to sort only the query output, you will need Aggregation Framework.