# Pagination of array field type on mongoose not working but works on mongo shell

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I want to paginate the field *rating* of my *product* collection. Upon trying this query on mongo shell,

```js
db.products.find({_id: ObjectId('610bd9233fdc66100f703dd4')}, {ratings: {$slice: [1,1]}}).pretty();
```

I got the expected result. Which is just one item from the rating field.

But I have tried the following queries using mongoose in my application but it keeps returning all the items in the ratings array.

```js
const ratings  = await Product.find({_id}).slice("ratings",[1, 1]).select("ratings").populate(populateQuery);

const ratings  = await Product.find({_id}, {ratings: {$slice: [1, 1]}}).select("ratings").populate(populateQuery);
```

I have checked mongoose website to be sure I am doing this right. [Mongoose Slice reference](https://mongoosejs.com/docs/api.html#query_Query-slice). I have also tried using this previously asked question [Pagination on array stored in a document field](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31792440/pagination-on-array-stored-in-a-document-field)

What am I doing wrong please. I have upgraded my mongoose package to the latest version also

Comment: Maybe `_id` is an string? Try to parse to `ObjectId`.

Answer (score 0):

Query.projection replace the projection on the query, so after running

```
.slice("ratings",[1, 1])
```

The projection will be `{ratings: {$slice:[1,1]}}`

Query.select modifies the projection in place, so after running

```
.select("ratings")
```

the `ratings` field of the projection will be set to `1`, so the resulting projection is: `{ratings: 1}`.

remove `.select("ratings")` from that line and it should work the way you intended.