# MongoDB .NET Driver - Pagination on array stored in a document field

Tags: c#, mongodb, pagination, mongodb-query, mongodb-.net-driver

How do I apply pagination in the `animals` field using C# with MongoDB .NET driver?

The schema is:

```
[{
    id: 1,
    name: "Tom",
    animals: ["cat", "dog", "fish", "bear", "dog1", "fish1", "bear1",]
},
{
    id: 2,
    name: "Rob",
    animals: ["shark", "snake", "fish", "bear", "panda"]
},
{
    id: 3,
    name: "Matt",
    animals: ["cat", "fish", "bear"]
}]
```

The solution is given [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31792440/pagination-on-array-stored-in-a-document-field) but I am finding it difficult to implement in C#.

Below is my code

```cs
var bsonSearchParams = new BsonDocument {
    new BsonElement ( "id" , id),
    new BsonElement  ( "animals", "{ $slice: [ 0, 3 ] }" )
};
var result = await collection.Find(bsonSearchParams).FirstOrDefaultAsync();
return result;
```

I am expecting the result

```
{
    id: 1,
    name: "Tom",
    animals: ["cat", "dog", "fish"]
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `bsonSearchParams` is not correct as you are including `slice` logic which is supposed in the projection.

You need [`.Slice()`](https://github.com/mongodb/mongo-csharp-driver/blob/master/src/MongoDB.Driver/ProjectionDefinitionBuilder.cs#L185) which is an extension method of `ProjectDefinition`.

```cs
public static ProjectionDefinition<TDocument> Slice<TDocument>(this ProjectionDefinition<TDocument> projection, FieldDefinition<TDocument> field, int skip, int? limit = null)
```

Your source code should be looked as below:

```cs
var bsonSearchParams = new BsonDocument 
{
    new BsonElement( "id" , id)
};

var bsonProjection = Builders<BsonDocument>.Projection
    .Slice("animals", 0, 3);

var result = await collection.Find(bsonSearchParams)
    .Project(bsonProjection)
    .FirstOrDefaultAsync();
```

> Sample code & output

[image]